# Connect to remote Oracle Database 2c using Node.js oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I want to connect to Oracle 12c remote. I have two vms. One with node package oracledb and oracle client libraries basic and sdk. Other vm has 12c installed. I tried chaning localhost to vm ip address in listener.ora files but no success. Can anyone guide what exactly I need to do so I can connect to remote oracle 12c using oracledb npm package. See below for the code

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : user,
    password      : password,
    connectString : connectString??
  },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often run Node.js in one VirtualBox VM and connect to a database running in a second VirtualBox VM (both hosted on the same MacBook).  For both, I use NAT networking.

- I set up 'port forwarding' in the DB VM so that the Oracle DB port (typically 1521) is available to the host OS.  This can be done in the VBox GUI.  To keep it easy, I use the same port number on both host & guest sides.
- In the Node.js VM, I use the IP address of the NAT gateway for the connect string.  For me, this gateway is 10.0.2.2 so my application `connectString` is like `10.0.2.2/orclpdb`

There are screen shots and details in my blog post https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/the-easiest-way-to-install-oracle-database-on-apple-mac-os-x

Of course, if you aren't using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), your solution will be different....

Comment: I am able to connect SQL developer tool with remote Oracle 12c but still trying to figure out the correct connectString that I need Node.js package oracledb. module.exports = {
  database: {
      user: 'hr',
      password: 'welcome',
      connectString: 'my.public.ip:1521/service-name'
  }

};

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can successfully connect to remote db using oracledb.